# iOS app ignore tabs and whitespace when parsing

Tags: ios, xml, parsing

I have an iphone app that is parsing xml that I generated myself. To make it easier to read, I'd like to be able to ignore the tab and return characters. If I have the xml formatted, the table view that displays the data is tabbed itself.

I saw this question:[XML Parsing: how to ignore whitespace or enter/return space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523949/xml-parsing-how-to-ignore-whitespace-or-enter-return-space)

but it doesnt seem to rid the tab/return characters, it just gets rid of all the whitespace. In other words, I want the content within the element itself to remain spaced while the tabs in the xml file (for formatting/ease of reading) to be ignored.

How can I do this?

Here is a sample of the XML that I want to display. It is the contents inside the XML:

```
        <Event>
            <EventName>STUFF TO DISPLAY</EventName>
            <EventImage>STUFF TO DISPLAY</EventImage>
        </Event>
```

Comment: Tab and return characters should count as whitespace. I'm assuming you have text inside XML that you wish to display? Or are you trying to display actual XML in your tableview? Maybe you could post a sample?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:-

```
NSStirng *string=@"Your String";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"[\r\n]|[ ^t^b]|[\t]" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
[regex enumerateMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length]) usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *match, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop)
{
    // your statement if it matches
}];
```

You can also do this:-

```
NSString *string= [originalString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfRegex:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",'\n','\t',@" "] withString:@" "];
```